# License error in JRules Rules Studio 7.1.1

Tags: jrules

I am new to Ilog JRules rules Studio.
Using JRules Rules Studio 7.1.1, i am testing a partucilar rule in Rules project using JUnit test case. I could see the below error, which i couldn't understand.

Caused by: ilog.jum.client700.IluSAMAccessDeniedException: At 2012-05-08 12:31:34 GMT, SAM 3.0.0.1040: Access denied to module 'RES4J'.
If you want to inspect your access key, please do the following: 
java -cp [location]sam.jar ilog.jum.client700.IluSAMAccessKey -summary
 To ensure you are inspecting the offending key, please check its digest is '4165df64e40f9c019099f9fc72d1bd79'

```
at ilog.jum.client700.IluSAM.<init>(IluSAM.java:569)
at ilog.jum.client700.IluSAM.createIluSAM(IluSAM.java:352)
at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.verifyRESLicense(IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.java:924)
... 47 more
```

Please help me, if anyone have any idea.

Thanks in advance.
Hari

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which WAS you are using but I would recommend that you re install RES.
The documentation is clear as crystal on how to install RES and RTS.

You said you are new, so I assume that you just downloaded it and hence your trial version is valid.
Otherwise, it may be because it has expired, double check that.

Hope it helps.
PS: check my answer to your other question about testing a rule, because you don't need RES to test a rule

Comment: Yes. I was tried to use Jrules 7.0.0 Execution server jars in Jrules studio 7.1.1 environment. That was the mistake. I completed reinstalled the version 7.0.0 for my development. Thanks for your information Damien.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason for this issue. I was trying with the Rules Studio 7.1.1 installation and using the rule execution server of version 7.0.0. sam.jar along with other jars for the version 7.0.0, which is causing the issue. RES is not available with Rules Studio  7.1.1 installation. So i installed the version 7.0.0, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I verify the JRules modules have been installed and licensed in JRules 7?](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21439091)

I had the same issue and I fixed it by replacing all sam.jar files with the latest one.